# Trying to understand what auth a website is using to login through python

Tags: python, html, authentication

I am trying to login into [this website](https://www.edline.net/) but when I look at the source, I cannot ascertain how its login works.  The file is a ".page" which confuses me and the code surrounding login is:

`<input type="text" id="screenName" name="screenName" tabindex="1"/>`

and

`<input type="password" id="password" name="kclq" maxlength="104" tabindex="2"/>`
but when i got to the submitting of the password it was not as clear:

Sign In

I tried using the modules *requests* and *mechanize* but neither seemed to work out:

```
import requests
import sys
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'
URL = 'http://edline.net/Index.page'

def main():
     session = requests.session(config = {'verbose': sys.stderr})

     login_data = {
     'screenName': USERNAME,
     'btnSignIn' : 'signIn',
     'password' : PASSWORD,
     }

     r = session.post(URL,data=login_data)

     r = session.get("https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page?") 
     #access a page requiring login
     print r.text
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How exactly would I go about doing this? The website itself seems to use javascript when logged in, but I just want to be able to access pages while logged in at the moment.

Also, could I be directed to a good starting place to be sufficient in reading html and knowing what kind of website I am dealing with?

Thanks

Comment: It's all done with Javascript. You could just drive a browser directly with Webdriver - See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807730/639295. The other option diagnostic thing you can do is use the developer tools in Chrome or Firefox to see what the request looks like going across the wire and then try and repeat it.

Comment: That worked, but I am looking to retrieve information without opening the browser, as the point of the program is to not have to open your browser in the first place (although that is an interesting program that I will keep for later use)

Comment: Sometimes you really do need to render the JavaScript though. You can use a virtual x buffer in order to achieve that. Have a look at Xvfb. Have a look at this post by one of my colleagues: http://devblog.resolversystems.com/?p=1111

Comment: Xvfb looks exactly like what I need thanks! (or rather, a much easier way to achieve what I want)

Answer (score 0):

use requests for login:

```
import requests
url = 'url'
data = {
      "screenName" : "username",
      "password" : "password",
      "btnSignIn" : "signIn",
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

that are easy